# What is this python code trying to do to this numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python line of code that I'm not sure what it is trying to do. I don't know what the name of the syntax is doing so I'm not sure how to google it. (I've tried: numpy array select).

result is of type numpy.ndarray

self.Xconstant is a list of False booleans

```
    result[:, self.Xconstant] = 0.0
```

Here is what self.Xconstant is:

```
[False, False, False]
```

I assume it is going to assign the 0.0 to the list element that happens to be True? so if I had it as:

```
# lets say result is [1, 2, 3]
self.Xconstant = [False, False, True]
result[:, self.Xconstant] = 0.0 # print result would give [1, 2, 0.0]
```

The weird part is that I get an error saying "too many indices for array".

Is my logic correct on what this line of python code is trying to modify? If so, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2 `res`:

```
In [50]: res = np.array([[1,2,3]])                                              
In [51]: res[:,[False,False,True]]                                              
Out[51]: array([[3]])
In [52]: res[:,[False,False,True]]=0                                            
In [53]: res                                                                    
Out[53]: array([[1, 2, 0]])
```

For 1d:

```
In [54]: res = np.array([1,2,3])                                                
In [55]: res[[False,False,True]]=0                                              
In [56]: res                                                                    
Out[56]: array([1, 2, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks! What is this called when you select elements in this way?

Comment: Often we use a term like `using a boolean mask`.  Or boolean array indexing: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
result[:, self.Xconstant]
```

should be:

```
result[self.Xconstant]
```

After all, `result` is 1d as you've said, and a 1d array doesn't need two indexers.

Comment: That, or perhaps `result` is wrong, or there are deeper problems. We can tell that this line doesn't fit with a 1D `result`, but we don't have enough information to completely determine what the code *should* look like.

Comment: this worked. at least in terms of not spitting out an error.

Comment: What is this called when you modify an array like this? I couldn't google it because I was not sure of the python syntax description.

Comment: @Cit5 Indexing, boolean masking.